# Ensure use of FIDO2 certified security key

Tags: webauthn, fido

We plan to introduce FIDO2 security keys and passwordless login for an IT system with sensitive data and would like to ensure that only *FIDO2 certified security keys* are used. How can we recognize such keys during registration and reject non-certified ones? Does WebAuthn provide any such information about the key? Is it possible at all?

Our aim is to prevent to use of security keys that are not properly implemented, e.g. keys that do not store the private key in secured hardware or skip the user verification. We want to prevent people from compromising security - accidentally or intentionally.

The IT system has a web user interface. So the communication with the FIDO2 key will be via HTML / Javascript / WebAuthn.

We are aware that we could purchase certified security keys, provision them centrally and then distribute them to the users. However, this process is costly and slow. Therefore, we would rather that users can bring or purchase their own FIDO2 keys and register them themselves.

Comment: Consider using `authenticatorSelection: { residentKey: "required", userVerification: "required" }` as part of the options when calling `navigator.credentials.create(...)`. Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#dictdef-authenticatorselectioncriteria.

Comment: Sorry but I don't think any of these options is helpful. Neither of the attributes guarantees that the security key is certified or that user verification is properly implemented. Or am I missing something?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

That's why my comment was a comment and not an answer.

These options are necessary but not sufficient to what you are asking for.

Comment: In order to allow only specific authenticators you need to ask for `"attestation": "direct"` and then check the `AAGUID` in the response.

Comment: Note that the FIDO2 metadata service has some U2F and UAF authenticators in it (without any `aaguid`). Not sure if it means they are FIDO2 certified though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible: the WebAuthn library you'll use will (probably - you still should check it) returns which type of attestation was used during registration. The `"none"` attestation means that you have no guarantee on the FIDO2 key used, while other types of attestation can give you various guarantees (use of FIDO1 or FIDO2).

For instance, you can restrict access to `Attestation CA` attestation type, using only FIDO2 metadata service. In this case only FIDO2 security keys registered in the metadata will allow a user to register.

Also, some libraries return the authenticator metadata involved in the registration, which means you can actually whitelist authorized security keys.

Long story short: it's technically possible and it should be handled by your FIDO2 / WebAuthn library.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very interesting pointers where I can dig deeper.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. A few additions: 1) check that the library you intend to use supports FIDO2 metadata. I've read in the past that some don't 2) Even for FIDO2 certified keys you can have different supported attestation types, with different security models. For instance, a `Basic attestation` means all the authenticators share the same private key, while `Attestation CA` means all authenticators have they own private key. Both can be issued by valid FIDO2 authenticators

Comment: You can check the README of the WebAuthn library I wrote to have an idea of what can be configured: https://github.com/tanguilp/wax